# mysql joining table with null

Tags: mysql

How can I join those two tables?

Breaks table

```
+----+-------------+
| id | description |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Sample      |
|  2 | Sample 2    |
+----+-------------+
```

User favorites

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | user_id | breaks_id |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 |       2 |         1 |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

My expected Output

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+
| breaks_id | user_id  | is_favorite  | description |
+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+
|         1 | 2        | 1            | Sample      |
|         2 | null     | null         | Sample      |
+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+
```

I want to view all list of breaks with user_id =1 then null if not favorites

Comment: How *are* they to be joined? That is, what fields form a relationship? And under what circumstances do those null values appear? And why are there not null values for breaks_id = 2 ("Sample 2")?

Comment: yes @Stidgeon sir i changed the breaks id to 2,

Comment: why do you want it to be null? 1 and 0 should work fine

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to use an OUTER JOIN here:

```
SELECT b.id AS break_id, f.user_id, f.id AS is_favorite, b.description
FROM breaks b
LEFT JOIN 
user_favorites f
ON b.id = f.breaks_id;
```

The LEFT JOIN is an outer join, that will SELECT all the records from the breaks table, and join them with corresponding entries in the user_favorites table. If there are no matches, the relevant fields will be Null.

Comment: yeah but how to add condition for specifc user_id ?

Answer (score 1):

it will work

```
SELECT br.id AS break_id, fv.user_id, fv.id AS is_favorite,
 br.description
 from breaks br
 left join  favorites fv
 on br.id = fv.id
 where fv.id is null;
```